# If $(M,R)\vDash \textrm{ZFC}$ must $R$ be a well-founded relation?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I ran into this question while trying to justify a claim made in Donald Monk's set theory notes that there exist countable transitive models of ZFC. A step in my sketch of this claim requires proving that if $(M,R)\vDash \phi$ for every $\phi\in\textrm{ZFC}$ then the relation $R$ on $M$ must itself be well-founded. I'm not sure if this actually holds or not.

Initially I thought that the well-foundedness axiom interpreted in $M$ may directly give the statement of well-foundedness for $(M,R)$ but this didn't work as well as I hoped. The well-foundedness axiom is given by
$$
\textrm{WF}=\forall x (x \neq \varnothing \rightarrow \exists y\in x(y\cap x)=\varnothing).
$$
Then $(M,R)\vDash \textrm{WF}$ is equivalent to
$$
\forall x\in M (\exists z\in M (zR x) \rightarrow \exists y\in M (yRx \wedge \forall z\in M (zR y \rightarrow \neg zRx))).
$$
The statement of well-foundedness for $R$ on the other hand is given by
$$
\forall x\subseteq M (\exists y\in x \rightarrow (\exists w\in x \ \forall z\in x \ \neg zRw))).
$$
Is there any way to establish well-foundedness from $(M,R)\vDash \textrm{ZFC}$? If not, will it this follow if we add the hypothesis that $M$ is transitive?

Comment: If you have a transitive model then the relation is wellfounded, because it’s the real $\in$ relation and $\in$ is wellfounded. Otherwise the relation can be not wellfounded.

Comment: If you look up "non-well-founded model of ZFC" you will get lots of hits. If any model of ZFC exists at all (i.e. if ZFC is consistent) then there are non-well-founded models (this is a simple compactness argument). Perhaps surprisingly, it is consistent that *only* non-well-founded models exist... in other words ZFC + Con(ZFC) does not prove well-founded models of ZFC exist (but per the first thing, it does prove that non-well-founded models exist).