# Justifying existence of countable transitive models - Donald Monk notes

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

It is a theorem proven in Donald Monk's set theory notes (page 184) that if $S$ is a consistent set of sentences containing ZFC, then if we add a constant $\mathbf{M}$ to the language of set theory the following set of sentences will be consistent:
$$
S\cup \{\mathbf{M} \textrm{ transitive}\} \cup \{|\mathbf{M}|=\omega\} \cup \{\phi^{\mathbf{M}}: \phi\in S\}.
$$

Monk concludes from this theorem that there exist countable transitive models of ZFC. But how can this fact can be derived from the theorem?

My attempt to prove the existence of countable transitive models was to pick $S=\textrm{ZFC}$ and then use completeness to show the existence of a model $(\mathcal{M},R)$ such that
$\mathcal{M} \vDash \textrm{ZFC}\cup \{\mathbf{M} \textrm{ transitive}\} \cup \{|\mathbf{M}|=\omega\} \cup \{\phi^{\mathbf{M}}: \phi\in \textrm{ZFC}\}.$ Then I was going to prove well-foundedness of the relation $R$, use Mostowski collapse to find a standard, transitive model $\mathcal{N}$ of the sentences, and then prove that $(\mathbf{M}^{\mathcal{N}},\in)$ had to be a countable, transitive model of ZFC. Unfortunately I learned from the responses to the post [If $(M,R)\vDash \textrm{ZFC}$ must $R$ be a Well-Founded Relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174155/if-m-r-vdash-textrmzfc-must-r-be-a-well-founded-relation) that we can't guarantee $R$ will be well-founded just from the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ models ZFC. So how can we justify Monk's assertion that his theorem proves the existence of countable transitive models of ZFC? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: What is the exact statement that Monk concludes from this theorem?  If he concludes (working in ZFC) that there exists a countable transitive model of ZFC, then he's just wrong.

Comment: @EricWofsey He says "The following corollary can be taken as a basis for working with countable transitive models of ZFC." Perhaps he is saying the existence of these models is consistent with ZFC?

Comment: That sounds like an intentionally vague statement that is going out of its way to avoid asserting that a countable transitive model actually exists.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok I think that resolves my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: What he's really saying is something along the lines of, "Certain arguments that can be elegantly formulated by assuming the existence of a countable transitive model can do away with that assumption by using this result".